# How to input HTTP data from a WSGI implementation  into Django?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I want to create a Django application that acts as middleware between two transparent WSGI implementations which simply pass along data. So far, all I want this application to do is log the HTTP data that it receives into a database for debugging purposes and then passes the information to the next WSGI implementation in line (which then handels this information to a web server like Apache)

My question is, how do I write a Django application that only receives existing HTTP data instead of creating it? I'm guessing this application would have no urls, just a view of some sort, a custom Django middleware component, and the database.
So how would I connect a WSGI implementation to the input of a Django app so that Django can read the information, log it, then output it? I know how to do the actual logging and outputting for I'm just confused about the inputting.

Comment: "two mod_wsgi instances"?  What -- exactly -- does this mean?  Please explain your architecture so we know what "two mod_wsgi instances" means.

Comment: Note that WSGI and Django app may have different database transaction lifecycles causing potential issues - I have run to this before. I did not find it very easy to build WSGI middleware with Django, as Django is hardwired to work with Django and Django only.

Comment: Please do not confuse WSGI the specification and mod_wsgi an implementation. Are you talking about Django being a WSGI middleware within an overall in process WSGI stack. If so, that has nothing to do with mod_wsgi albeit that the whole stack could be hosted on mod_wsgi, or any other WSGI compliant server for that matter. So, be careful about what terminology you are using else you will just confuse people.

Comment: I apologize for my misuse of terminology. Yes, I meant to say that I'm trying to build a Django middelware app within an overall in process WSGI stack. If Django isn't suited very well for this task, would you recommend that I use a different framework all together?

Answer (score 0):

There was a GSOC project in the past related to making it easier/possible to plug WSGI middleware into Django. Code at:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/branches/soc2009/http-wsgi-improvements

I don't know what happened to that.

Alex Gaynor has also played with better WSGI integration:

http://alexgaynor.net/2010/jan/11/hot-django-wsgi-action-announcing-django-wsgi/

If you don't get an answer here then suggest asking on Django users mailing list.